# PHP / MSSQL / PDO connection/drivers

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, odbc

I'm having a bit of a nightmare when trying to do what I thought was something very simple in PHP. I haven't any experience with PHP so I've been relying on articles/forums etc.

All I want to do is query an MSSQL database, and output on a page. I've been coming across several issues which the error messages tell me are driver problems.

My host (a2hosting) tells me they have Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 installed, as 11 is incompatible with the server. They tell me pdo_sqlsrv is enabled for PHP 5.6 which I can select, so I shouldn't have a problem (through Plesk I can select 5.6.34, 7.0.28, 7.1.15, 7.2.3 - however unable to view phpinfo(). They also told me to include the driver information in the code.

I'm unable to find any snippets or useful information specific to my problem, so I'm hoping the Stack Overflow world can help. (I've been trying to use examples from Microsoft & PHP manual so this may be a little all over the place)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 

$mssqldriver = '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}';

$hostname='my.ip';
$dbname='dbname';
$username='user';
$password='pass';

$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$hostname;Database=$dbname", $username, 
$password);

$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); 
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT, 1 ); 

$query = 'select * from salesdata'; 

// simple query 
$stmt = $conn->query( $query ); 
while ( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){ 
print_r( $row['agent'] ."\n" ); 
} 


$stmt = null; 
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712' in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\o2live.co.uk\httpdocs\testfile10.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\o2live.co.uk\httpdocs\testfile10.php(16): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=6...', 'username', 'password') #1 {main} thrown in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\o2live.co.uk\httpdocs\testfile10.php on line 16

Just a heads up I have a shared hosting account so I'm unable to make changes to drivers/software etc.!

Happy to use a completely different approach if there is one, I've tried several but this one seems to be what my host is suggesting

Comment: Contact your hosting provider's support for the error message you are receiving. There is nothing we can do for you here.

Comment: Hi GrumpyCrouton, thanks for your response.. My host said they use driver version 13 and pdo_sqlsrv should work, they told me to contact a web developer for help (useful!).. As far as you can see, should my code work?

Comment: The code looks fine - the error obviously states that version 13 will not work as **_version 11 is required_**. Errors don't really lie, it tells you exactly what you need. If your code was wrong, it would tell you that instead of the error you are getting. Version 11 and 13 can be installed independently of each other and at the same time on a server. You could try to change `$mssqldriver` to `{ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}` and add it to your connection string: `"sqlsrv:Server=$hostname;Database=$dbname;Driver=$mssqldriver"`, perhaps that would work?

Comment: If your host won't install version 11, then this probably won't work as your code requires version 11. If they believe this error is wrong, it should be up to them to prove that and to get it working or else they really are denying you any support and if I were you in that case I would find a new host.

Comment: I amended the conn string and get the same error, the host aren't able to install 11 as it's incompatible with the OS on the server apparently. Is there a different method I could use that uses version 13?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: OK thanks a lot, really appreciate the help.